# What is the best option for multiple live client-server (socket-like) connections?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, websocket, connection

I am currently developing a new web-app, that is based on multiple live connections between the clients and the server. The clients are able to send data to the server (in `text/JSON` form), and an admin at the server side can send responses back (also in `text/JSON` form), depending on the data that the client sent.

It is important that these connections are live (like socket connections), because this is part of a live verification process (*data security not relevant in this question*). Here is a quick sketch of what I was thinking about:

[image]

To explain the **server** task a little more:

- All connections are listed in a table on the separate page that represents (and is hosted on) the server.
- This table is updated dynamically / live, and for each connection, the data sent by the client gets displayed in the table. This table can be compared to a `SQL` database.
- A server admin can send responses to each individual client, and using buttons in the table, responses can be sent to the client, and connections can be closed etc.

Connections can be initiated from different users at different domains, and all lead to a single server, where the data gets collected and handled. Ofcourse, the connection from the client-side is handled with `JavaScript`, and for back-end code, I'm currently using `PHP`. But switching to `NodeJS` or any other scripting language is no problem.

I'm asking this here because I have little to no experience in this kind of programming. With live connections. I'm looking for a solution to my problem that I sketched above. **And I'm not asking for a straight up answer / code**, but rather a tip to what kind of solutions I could use for this.

I myself was thinking about `WebSockets` / `WebRTC connections`, but I don't know if this is the right solution for this problem.

P.S: If it's possible that the client doesn't see a port number in the URL, that would be a big plus!

Comment: Yep, websockets. WebRTC is more aimed at audio/video, and is usually peer-to-peer rather than client/server (as per your diagram). NodeJS is definitely better at being a websocket server than PHP. As is ASP.NET 5 with SignalR. SignalR is great actually because it abstracts away the socket implementation detail - even to the extent that if it encounters a client which doesn't support websockets it will fall back on other techniques such as AJAX or HTTP long polling, without you having to write any extra code.

Comment: `If it's possible that the client doesn't see a port number in the URL`...chances are, the client won't notice a websocket URL at all, cos it's likely to be buried in the JavaScript source code somewhere, and most people don't go poking around in that. The only thing most people see is the URL of the main page they've loaded into their browser.